# Adding "active" class to a the toggle itself jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Okay so I have some jQuery code that I am using to get tabs to work.

Now this is my problem, I want the toggle it self to have a `"active"` class added to it when someone clicks on the toggle. I don't want an active class on the content, but instead the toggle.

Here is my jQuery Code

```
function toggleMeMirror(a){

// hide all

jQuery('.episodemirrors').hide();

//  show one

var e=document.getElementById(a);

if(!e) return true;

    if(e.style.display=="none"){  

        e.style.display="inline"

    } else {

        e.style.display="none"

    }

return true;

}
```

Here is my HTML code for the toggle.. not the content.

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" onclick="return toggleMeMirror('post-<?php the_ID(); ?>')" >Toggle</div>
```

This is where I want the active class so possibly make the class `active` when someone clicks on it so I can style it differently.

This is my HTML for my content

`<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="episodemirrors"> Content </div>`

Comment: Why does your `div` have a return value?

Comment: The element has a class, but you're trying to get it with getElementById ?

Comment: @adeneo - It looks to me like the `div` has the `id` in the argument which is a different element. So He hides all elements which would have that id and shows the one in the argument. But still, this looks like a "I was hoping you could do this for me. Here is what I want: ..." type of question.

Comment: The actual content has the id.

Comment: Alright, fixed the class to ID. So I just need a "active" class added...

Could I use something like this `element.addClass('active');` ?

Answer (score 0):

You use jQuery and you have a unique toggler id. So, you can do this inside your existing function:

```
$('.post-[id]').addClass('active');
```

Some suggestions though:

1. Since your toggler classes have unique ids, you may want to have them use ids instead of classes.
2. Instead of doing e.style.display, you can use jQuery's toggleClass which keeps track of adding and removing a class for you. You start by hiding all classes whenever you trigger the function, so you could just turn display on for that div.
3. Since you use jQuery, you can use that to trigger the click as well.

A simple example based on your code:

```
<div class="trigger" id="[id]">Toggle</div>

$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $('.episodemirrors').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#post-'+id).css('display', 'inline');
});
```

Comment: Do note though that when I wrote the comment, you used a unique class instead of an id on the trigger. Since then, I see you've changed your example. It's a good effort, but now, you instead have the same id for both trigger and content divs, which isn't going to work.

Comment: I am using 'id' for the divs now. I just need a 'active' class added now. 

Could you possibly show me where I can add that code into my current jQuery? I am a complete noob at jQuery :(

Comment: How should I change my jQuery then? I am sorry, I don't know much about jQuery. You can see my current jQuery code at the top. Since you've recommended to have ids instead of classes. Then I'll just need a class="active" whenever someone clicks on the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I think that easiest way is to make it this way:

html:

```
<div class="spoiler">
     <div class="toggle">Toggle</div>
     <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.spoiler .content {
    display: none;
}
```

js:

```
$(".spoiler .toggle").click(function(){
    $(".spoiler .toggle.active").removeClass("active").next().hide();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next().toggle();
})
```

Comment: There are multiple tabs and multiple content. When one tab is clicked the rest have to be hidden.

Comment: Have added some code, so now you will have all all active toggles disapear, and make active one appear

Comment: Content is found above the toggle. Here is a link of how it works at the moment: http://phanime.com/43902/dansai-bunri-no-crime-edge-online-episode-11/